# fpdtc.dll register on Windows 10 for Office 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am currently trying to fix an issue with an old MS Access Database 2003 now running on MS Access 2016 on Windows 10/64 bit machine.
When loading the Access Database I am told the `fpdtc.dll` needs registering.
I have downloaded this and added it to the `System32`, `SysWoW64` and  application folder for access.
I have now tried to register the .DLL file but get the message

> The module "Fpdtc.dll" failed to load / The specified module could not be found.

If I now look at references in VBA I can see the `fptdtc` is available but the path is an old location where I have had this access database working in the past but have since upgraded my Office.

Can someone help me to register the file correctly/fix issue?

Comment: 1. I expect the dll is a 32-Bit dll. So it won't run in `System32`, the 64-Bit folder. 2. If your new Office 2016 is 64-Bit Office you will need a 64-Bit dll to be registered. 3. If you can't get a 64-Bit dll then try to exchange your 64-Bit Offce by a 32-Bit Office, the 32-Bit dll should register well in the correct 32-Bit folder, I guess?

Comment: I have just followed the instructions here and as long as I copy the .dll files in to both system32 and syswow64 locations this should still work "http://www.dlldownloader.com/fpdtc-dll/"

Comment: If you can't register the dll at all, maybe it needs further dlls? Maybe you need to install the software where it came from?

The source from yhere you got it looks not really trustful to me...

It looks like this dll comes from `Microsoft Office FrontPage Design-Time Controls` as stated here: https://www.processlibrary.com/de/directory/files/fpdtc/309290/

Maybe you can install this software and so register the proper dll?

Comment: The link for the download is fine "thankfully" used it before but I will try downloading Microsoft Office Front Page Design-Time Controls to see if I can register the DLL correctly.  The object that should load is a calendar which I believe was discontinued some time ago.